# Двоеточие после "например" в начале предложения

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые, вводные-слова, двоеточие

**Отчитывайтесь в формате «задачи — сложности — действия — результат». Например: «Иван Иванович, в начале месяца вы поставили мне задачу увеличить продажи на 20 %. Сейчас кризис, поэтому наблюдается падение спроса на рынке. Однако благодаря ребрендингу и новой рекламной компании мне всё же удалось увеличить продажи на 32,7 %».**

Можно ли поставить двоеточие вместо запятой, ибо здесь вводится цитата и можно считать предложение неполным:

**Например, *это может быть так*: «Иван Иванович, в начале месяца...»**

Comment: Если пунктуационная проблема в предложении не переходит на следующее, не следует давать пространные цитаты. Тем более,  выделять их жирным кеглем: выделение — мера штучная.

Comment: @shampar, Вы правите слишком решительно. Именно из-за пространности цитаты РиммаМихайлова видит в ней перечисление, которое влияет на пунктуацию. А после правки  ее ответ лишен смысла.

Comment: Есть стандартные признаки перечисления. У Вас в тексте точки после каждой фразы делают их отдельными предложениями. Если это даётся не нумерованным набором, значит оно не является перечислением.  Определитесь сами, ведь это несложно.

Comment: @shampar, Я не вижу здесь перечисления, о чем и написал в своем ответе, но получилось так, что Вы своей правкой как бы перечеркнули ответ Риммы Михайловой, я это неэтично (даже если получилось случайно, и несмотря на то, что мы оба с ее позицией не согласны).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы тоже поставил двоеточие, но не по причине перечисления (я его здесь не вижу), а потому, что слово *например* вводит прямую речь (*Например, говорите так: "...."*).

Answer (score 0):

1. Если *например* стоит после обобщающего слова (или словосочетания) и далее следует перечисление, то перед *например* ставится запятая, а после него двоеточие.
   ***Поздней осенью еще можно найти в лесу грибы, например: зелёнки, грузди, опята.***
2. Если предложение начинается со слова *например* и далее следует перечисление, то также ставится двоеточие.
   ***Поздней осенью еще можно найти в лесу грибы. Например: зелёнки, грузди, опята.***

"Формат «задачи — сложности — действия — результат»". Эта фраза спокойно заменяется одним обобщающим словом — **позиции** (или пункты, или положения).
Отчитывайтесь по позициям, по пунктам, по положениям.

*Иван Иванович, в начале месяца вы поставили мне задачу увеличить продажи на 20 %* (позиция **задачи**); *сейчас кризис, поэтому наблюдается падение спроса на рынке* (позиция **сложности**); *благодаря ребрендингу и новой рекламной кампании* (позиция **действия**); *мне всё же удалось увеличить продажи на 32,7 %* (позиция **результат**).

3. В Вашем контексте правильно [**рекламной кАмпании**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti?layout=item&id=36_192).
   (Сравните: благодаря новой рекламной компании "Альфа и Омега" или благодаря сотрудничеству с новой рекламной компанией.)
4. Я бы выделила оборот "благодаря ребрендингу и новой рекламной кампании" запятыми — для его подчеркивания (как одну из позиций).

**Отчитывайтесь в формате «задачи — сложности — действия — результат». Например: «Иван Иванович, в начале месяца вы поставили мне задачу увеличить продажи на 20 %. Сейчас кризис, поэтому наблюдается падение спроса на рынке. Однако, благодаря ребрендингу и новой рекламной кампании, мне всё же удалось увеличить продажи на 32,7 %».**

5. **Например, это может быть так: «Иван Иванович, в начале месяца...»**

Всё правильно: вводное слово *например* обособляется по общим правилам (ставится запятая), а перечисление начинается после слова *так* (двоеточие ставится после него).

[**Запятые и двоеточие при слове «например»**](http://gramatik.ru/zapyatye-i-dvoetochie-pri-slove-naprimer/)

Comment: Вам не кажется, что ситуация с однородными членами после обобщающего слова здесь притянута за уши? Указан формат, а далее идёт пример применения данного формата. Пункт 3: опечатка, извиняюсь. Пункт 4: оборот с предлогом благодаря здесь тесно связан со сказуемым и не выделяется интонационно. Пункт 5: я это предложение привел в качестве пояснения, какие члены могут быть пропущены, если исходное предложение является неполным.

Comment: Мне кажется, что Вам надо откатить правку. Я оперирую в ответе предложениями, которых в теперешней версии вопроса, собственно, и нет - никто ничего (кроме нас с Вами) не понимает. Да и неудобно возвращаться каждый раз к "доправке".